# Which programming language was PhpStorm programmed in?

Tags: phpstorm

The logical answer might be PHP, but I honestly don't have a clue.

Comment: it is hardly logical that a 'fat client' be programmed in php. PhpStorm is probably programmed in Java : it uses the same core as all other Jetbrains products.

Comment: I actually would not have said, if asked, that PhpStorm was written in PHP, but I stupidly referred to the name of the program itself. However, you are right, the word 'logical' was a bad choice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PhpStorm is built on IntelliJ IDEA, which is written in Java.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm

Comment: Java .. and now Kotlin.